# Elasticsearch Child object id search

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

i have a document which looks like this

```
 document
 {
 Title:string,
 Id:integer
 Tags:List<Tag>
 }

 Tag
 {
  Id:integer,
  Value:string,
  Type:string
 }
```

now i have parameters serchtext and tagid i need to get the results based on this parameters get all the objects which matches the search term and contains the tagid passed

this is what i had been tryin but no luck

```
     var fuzzySearchResult = client.Search<Products>(s => s
            .From(o)
            .Size(50)
            .Index(index)
            .Query(filterQuery).Filter(ff=>ff.Term(t=>t.Tags.Where(id=>id.Id==tagid).FirstOrDefault().Id,Id))

        );
```

Comment: Could you explain how do you declare your filterQuery? The problem is filtering by tagid or by searchtext?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var searchtext="term";
var tagid=1;
var documents=  client.Search<Document>(x => x.Query( s =>s.Term(p=>p.Title, searchtext) && s.Term(z => z.Tags.Select(t=>t.Id), tagId)));
```

This query search all the Documents that have the **searchtext** as a part of its title and the tag with id=**tagId**.